# Fast linear system solver for large systems

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, solver, differential-equations

How do I solve a large linear system where the system matrix is banded diagonal? Just using `\` takes longer than I would like. I am open to use iterative methods, if this is the only alternative, but is there any known efficient m-files already implemented? What should I look for?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I hope you meant just using ` \ `.

Comment: Would be nice to see your code

Comment: What is the structure of your problem other than being banded? Symmetric? Positive Definite? Diagonally Dominant?

Comment: What is "large"? How sparse is the system? Is the matrix real or complex?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Sure, sorry for the typo.

Comment: @Nitish It is a system of coupled PDE in finite differences, so it is not symmetric in principle, the size of the band is pretty small compared to the size of the matrix (O(10) vs O(1000)).

Comment: @horchler The matrix is real. Large is the size of the system O(1000)